# Apache ActiveMQ Camel failover

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

We use MQ as a primary route to transfer messages. It is integral to how our system works. There are times the message broker fails, and with it all the associated queues. Is there a way, in camel, to kickstart a failover, and revert back to master when it's up?

Comment: Which Mq are you using , if you are using Activemq then there is a failover topology in the mq itself , read the documentation here https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/04/using-activemq-masterslave-configuration-with-failover-protocol.html

Comment: Its the JMS Client that needs to have failover built-in. ActiveMQ broker has that. Not sure what IBM MQ offers. But looks there for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general, messaging systems do not want to interrupt client -> server communication for any reason. Once a failover connection is re-established, the preference is to stay connected to that server. IBM MQ supports client failover as well, but I do not know of a way to do a rebalance after a failover has occurred.

Media Driver's Integrated Console supports rebalancing ActiveMQ/JBoss A-MQ clients after a failover or before a maintenance window: https://mediadriver.com/software/  (see: Client rebalancing video at the bottom)

Disclaimer: I am a co-founder of Media Driver and head up the product development of the Integrated Console.